# Applying :not() with :after

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a little css code to add an underline to the **H2** headings in my blog posts:

```
.post h2:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    border: .5px  dashed ;
}
```

This works.

For a specific post, I don't want this underlines applied. I added an additional class to the **H2** headings that I want to stylize differently: `.h2lines`

Now, I can exclude this new class (`.h2lines`) when applying CSS directly to `.post h2`. For example:

```
.post h2:not(.h2line) {
    color: #blue;}
```

This works. It will make all post **H2** blue except the ones with additional class.

However, I can't get it to work on the `:after` element:

```
.post h2::after:not(.h2line)
```

This does not work. It removes the underline from all **H2** headings.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You just use,

```
.post h2:not(.h2line)::after{}
```